# Getting node-inspector to open debugging browser page on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, debugging, node-inspector

When I first installed the latest version of node-inspector (0.9.2) running it with 'node-inspector app.js' I had the debugging session opened automatically in Chrome and the app was automatically running at localhost:5000.

Now running the same command I just get this:

```
D:\Work\examples\mozaik-demo-master>node-inspector app.js
Node Inspector v0.9.2
Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 to start debugging.
```

And then I have to open another prompt window and run the app with 'node --debug app.js' then open the browser windows at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858' and 'localhost:5000'.

This is so much an overhead, how can I make it work as it did the first time? Installing and uninstalling node-inspector doesn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: how about running `node-debug app.js` only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `node-inspector` was never opening Chrome. It was always starting the backend web server only.

You should use the command `node-debug` instead. This command will start the backend, start the application in debug mode, and open the browser for you.

```
D:\Work\examples\mozaik-demo-master>node-debug app.js
```

Comment: That is so true, I thought I was using node-inspector. Thanks for reminding me).

Answer (score 0):

`node-debug` is NOT well maintained. I'm now using `devtool`: https://github.com/Jam3/devtool. It's great.